# Dynamically version a pyproject.toml package without importing runtime dependencies at build time

Tags: pip, versioning, pyproject.toml

I'm writing research ML code and for reproducability I want to keep track of the code's version when each experiment is ran, similar to how nightly builds of various software track their version. I structure my code as a `pip` package. In `setup.py` I had a function `get_hash` using `git-python` to check the git hash at build time and insert it as `__version__` of the installed package, which can be later saved a training log file.

Now I'm trying to modernise the build system and use `pyproject.toml`/`setup.cfg` definition. It does allow for dynamic versioning but only by capturing an attribute from the package built. This means I need to put `get_hash` in the package itself, which in turn makes all my package dependencies become build dependencies as well (since the package needs to be imported at build time). This is bad because I want to build wheels on my laptop, without the heavy-weight GPU-enabled dependencies.

I found a hackaround by creating what is technically a second dummy package, called `my_package_version`, which consists solely of `__init__.py` and uses `git-python` to set its `__version__`. Then in `pyproject.toml` I can write

```ini
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "my_package_version.__version__"}
```

This does the job, but feels very hacky and I end up installing `my_package` and a "ghost" `my_package_version`, which could be confusing to some users. What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Setuptools will primarily attempt to statically analyze the module for the version attribute, so runtime deps shouldn't be required at build time. You could also try eg `hatch`, whose dynamic version determination might work better for you.

Comment: https://setuptools-git-versioning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/differences.html has a list of tools which support this and compares their differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: use or re-implement [setuptools_scm](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm).

```ini
[project]
name = "my_package"
dynamic = ["version"]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=45", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.2"]

[tool.setuptools_scm]
# Empty is fine
```

Implementation from scratch requires moving the version code to a package hooking entry points for [dynamic metadata](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#dynamic-metadata) in the same way:

```ini
[project.entry-points."setuptools.finalize_distribution_options"]
setuptools_scm = "setuptools_scm._integration.setuptools:infer_version"
```

You'll get called for every package you install, so care is required to avoid overriding your dependencies' versions. I recommend reading the code for [setuptools_scm](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm) and its [infer_version](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/blob/main/src/setuptools_scm/_integration/setuptools.py#LL100C5-L100C18) entry point in particular.

If it all seems a bit much, PyPA already did the work.